# C#, strange things with Random.Next

Tags: c#, random

I have a class for snails.

```
    class snails
{
    Random speedRand = new Random();
    public int SnaleOffset = 9;
    int speed;
    public void snailChangeSpeed() { this.speed = speedRand.Next(3)+1; }
    public void snailGo() { this.SnaleOffset = this.SnaleOffset + this.speed; }
}
```

I have created 4 snail objects, that are supposed to change their moving speed when the timerSnailSpeed timer ticks...

```
        private void timerSnailSpeed_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Snail1.snailChangeSpeed();
        Snail2.snailChangeSpeed();
        Snail3.snailChangeSpeed();
        Snail4.snailChangeSpeed();

    private void timerSnailMove_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Snail1.snailGo();
        Snail2.snailGo();
        Snail3.snailGo();
        Snail4.snailGo();
        imgSnail1.Left = Snail1.SnaleOffset;
        imgSnail2.Left = Snail2.SnaleOffset;
        imgSnail3.Left = Snail3.SnaleOffset;
        imgSnail4.Left = Snail4.SnaleOffset;
    }
```

Yet the problem is that their speed does not change randomly for each snail object, rather then for all of them together. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you constructing the Snail1 through Snail4 instances?

Comment: snails Snail1;
        snails Snail2;
        snails Snail3;
        snails Snail4;

Comment: and then after InitializeComponent(); Snail1 = new snails();, etc.

Comment: Rob: That's the var definition, not the constructor call.  How are you constructing the instances that get assigned to the vars?

Comment: Ok, just checking that each var gets a different instance, not all 4 pointing to the same object.

Comment: yes, this was my initial thought, too. but all of them are different objects. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating four instances of `Random` and since the default seed is time based, they will most likely all produce the same sequence of random numbers. Let the instances of `snails` share the same instance of `Random` to avoid this.

Comment: >>> Let the instances of snails share the same instance of Random to avoid this. 
Didn't really understand... how do I do this?

Comment: Or give each Random a different seed, such as perhaps the object hash value.  speedRand = new Random((int32)this.GetHashValue());

Comment: Pass the random object on the creation of a Snail (add a parameter to the constructor and then call 'snails Snail1 = new snails(random);'.

Comment: @Rob - make the speedRand variable static

Comment: @Rob: You can either inject an instance of `Random` via the constructor for `snails` or just create a static instance yourself.